# Display child class name jQuery droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, children, droppable

I am using the .droppable function to display playing card names. I am able to display the id and class of the span element /-not included-/ but I would also like to display the `p` class as well. The top part of the code is the function im using. In between the span tags is where I want to be able to display "Ace" with the other info I will be displaying on the div. Thanks.

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$( function() {
$( "span" ).draggable();

$( ".selector" ).droppable({
activate: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
        .find( "p" )
        .html( cardSuit + ' ' + cardNum);
        }}

});
```

HTML:

```
<p id="cards" class="ui-widget-content">

<span id="card26 " class="clubs ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">

<p class="Ace">A</p> <!--This here-->

</span>
</p>

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
      <p id="dropText">Drop here
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't have a `<p>` inside of a `<span>` , nor inside another `<p>`.

Comment: @Musa Ok ill test everything on '<divs>' instead, thanks.